# Comparing two time types in Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to make a function that checks the current time, and tells me if it's before or after sunrise, sunset, dusk, dawn and noon.

But I'm a bit stuck in how to compare the time types I get :(

Can anyone help me out?

This is my code:

```
now = datetime.now()
now_time = now.time()

print ('\nTime now is %s \n' % now_time)

city_name = 'Stockholm'

a = Astral()

a.solar_depression = 'civil'

city = a[city_name]

print('Information for %s/%s\n' % (city_name, city.region))

timezone = city.timezone

print('Timezone: %s' % timezone)

print('Latitude: %.02f; Longitude: %.02f\n' % \
(city.latitude, city.longitude))

today = datetime.strptime(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), '%Y-%m-%d')

sun = city.sun(date=datetime.date(today), local=True)

dawn = str(sun['dawn'])[11:-6]
sunrise = str(sun['sunrise'])[11:-6]
noon = str(sun['noon'])[11:-6]
sunset = str(sun['sunset'])[11:-6]
dusk = str(sun['dusk'])[11:-6]

print('Dawn:    %s' % dawn)
print('Sunrise: %s' % sunrise)
print('Noon:    %s' % noon)
print('Sunset:  %s' % sunset)
print('Dusk:    %s \n' % dusk)

if now_time > datetime.strptime(dawn, '%H:%M:%S'):
    print ('Time is after dawn')
else:
    print ('Time is before dawn')
```

It returns this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 63, in <module>
    If now_time > datetime.strptime(dawn, '%H:%M:%S'):
TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to datetime.datetime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract a `time` object from a `datetime` object, use the `datetime.time()` function or the `datetime.timetz()` function. The latter will retain timezone information, while the former will not.

So change the problem line to this:

```
if now_time > datetime.strptime(dawn, '%H:%M:%S').time():
```